# Make my user and debian-transmission read-write each other files

Tags: permissions, nas

I'm kinda bugged with this issue.

I had just built a NAS server with Ubuntu 20.04 and am installing Transmission on it and moving torrents from old server.

Inside the RAID5 there's the download folder, where among other things are files created by Transmission from its downloads. This RAID5 also has SMB share set to use my user.

The issue is that files downloaded by Transmission are created under debian-transmission user and group. Under default settings I'm unable to write, move or delete these files. And I'm moving torrents from my old server to the new one, these moved files are created under my user and group, then Transmission is unable to write on them!

I had created a group named `naswrite` and placed both users on it and made a `chgrp -R naswrite downloads && chmod -R g+rw downloads`. That allows both users to write on all existing files, but new files created after that are again created under the group of who created them and aren't available to write for the other group!

I'm trying to avoid adding my user to Transmission group and vice-versa.

The best help I'd found was https://superuser.com/questions/381416/how-do-i-force-group-and-permissions-for-created-files-inside-a-specific-directo, I tried that and it didn't work. When I create a test file, it's still created under my group.

Only think I can figure is to create a script that runs the above command and set it to run every few minutes on crontab, but that seems ugly. What's the best practice for this?

Comment: Did setting setgid bit on the `downloads` directory (`chmod g+s downloads`) not help?

Comment: No, new created files are created on user's group.